# Should g++ 4.4.7 -std=gnu++0x compile the "for each" construct?

Tags: c++, c++11, foreach, g++

I'm currently stuck with g++ 4.4.7, and I tried using it (with the -std=gnu++0x flag) to compile a c++ program that used the "foreach" construct:

```
190: void
191: Block::get_record_types(D_RecordType_Vector& record_type_vector) const {
192:    for ( D_Record_Map::value_type rt_v_i  : _records) { 
193:
194:        record_type_vector.push_back(rt_v_i.first);
195:    }
196: }
```

The first error makes me think it just didn't recognize the construct:

```
./c/Block.cpp:192: error: expected initializer before ':' token
./c/Block.cpp:196: error: expected primary-expression before '}' token
./c/Block.cpp:196: error: expected ';' before '}' token
./c/Block.cpp:196: error: expected primary-expression before '}' token
./c/Block.cpp:196: error: expected ')' before '}' token
./c/Block.cpp:196: error: expected primary-expression before '}' token
./c/Block.cpp:196: error: expected ';' before '}' token
```

This compiled correctly on Apple clang-425.

I realize g++4.4.7 is old, but shouldn't it even *recognize* the new construct, given the compiler flag?

Comment: "To enable C++0x support, add the command-line parameter -std=c++0x to your g++ command line. Or, to enable GNU extensions in addition to C++0x extensions, add -std=gnu++0x. GCC 4.7 and later support -std=c++11 and -std=gnu++11 as well." [C++0x/C++11 Support in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, support was added in GCC 4.6, see http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/changes.html#cplusplus and http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html

> I realize g++4.4.7 is old, but shouldn't it even *recognize* the new construct, given the compiler flag?

No, why should it?  You're suggesting that someone modifies the C++ parser to understand a new feature, just to reject it. That would be a waste of time - if someone has the time to modify the parser why not just add support for the feature?  Otherwise they've got to modify the code, add testcases (to test it *doesn't support* the feature) etc. etc.  Code changes to recognise new syntax don't just happen magically.

Comment: for sure 1 error-message about an unimplemented feature is way better than 7 errors about suspicious syntax-errors.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Actually, using GCC 4.6+ without `-std=c++0x` or `-std=c++11` will give you 1 nice error: `range-based ‘for’ loops are not allowed in C++98 mode`. That is, as soon as the parser was upgrade to recognize the feature, code was added to accept it __and__ to reject it, depending on the standard in use.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb, yes, of course, it's better, but it doesn't happen for free, _someone has to do the work to make it happen_. Once someone had time to do the work you get support _and_ an helpful error in C++98 mode, but expecting an error from GCC 4.4 released circa 2009 is optimistic at best.

Comment: Accepted as answer, but -1 for edit.  I knew that "some features were experimental" and thought that the foreach construct was at least a known possibility at the time.

Comment: @Chap, whether the features are experimental or not, to make a compiler recognise new syntax _someone has to do the work_, so expecting the compiler to understand every kind of experimental syntax years before it's standardized is completely unrealistic. That's simply not how the real world works. Can you show **any** compiler from 2009 which understood that syntax?

Comment: Please, sir.  Don't look for excuses to be condescending.  I was not complaining that someone (you?) had been shirking their open-source development duties.  I was just honestly confused by the error.  Your initial answer, that the support I sought was added in 4.6, answered my question fully, and I appreciate that.

Answer (score 3):

GCC 4.4.0 was [released April 23, 2009](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-announce/2009/msg00002.html). The wording for range-based for loops was [finalized July 16, 2009](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2930.html). I'm not aware of any compiler writers with precognitive abilities.

Comment: Your answer is more along the lines of what i was thinking... i.e. it's not that the 4.4.7 compiler chose not to implement the feature... but rather the requirements for the feature weren't defined (aka "finalized")... you can't implement a feature without well-defined requirements (especially for a complex tool used by billions of people like `g++`).